# Git bash is installed and integrated but I don't see it in the terminal list of vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

All other terminals are visible [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5RGw.png)in the list like command prompt, etc. But, Git bash is not showing up. I am worried If I have installed and integrated Git properly. I am sharing the settings.json. Please, let me know where I am wrong or I can share more info

Answer (score 0):

Open you settings.json file and add the following at last.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows":{"GIT BASH ADDED ":{"path":"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"},  },
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash"
```

Remember to add the path of your git-bash.exe correctly (wherever you have installed it).

see the screenshot for you reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now it's showing up in the list. But, when I click it, it opens up as an external terminal. Is there anything else I need to do to make it open as an integrated terminal?